# Confusion about when Angular and when service calls need digest

Tags: angularjs

I'm running into an issue that I've managed to find a fix for but I was looking for some feedback to ensure I'm doing this the right way.

I have a function in a controller that makes a call to a service. If it fails, for whatever reason, I display an error message to the user.

```
//Controller
vm.login = function() {
  vm.error = "";
  Sessions.create(vm.user)
  .then(function(result) {
    $state.go("home");
  })
  .catch(function(result) {
    vm.error = result.data.errors;
  });
};

//Service
Sessions.create = function(data) {
  return $http.post(API + "sessions", data)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
};

//View
.alert.alert-danger(role="alert" ng-show="vm.error") {{vm.error}}
```

The code above works exactly as intended. When it hits `vm.error = result.data.errors` that error message is correctly displayed to the user.

As I attempt to add some additional functionality to that service (localforage) I'm getting some weird behavior. Here's my new code:

```
//Controller
vm.newLogin = function() {
  vm.error = "";
  Sessions.login(vm.user)
  .then(function(result) {
    $state.go("home");
  })
  .catch(function(result) {
    vm.error = result.data.errors;
    $scope.$digest();  //NEED THIS?!?
  });
};

//Services
Sessions.create = function(data) {
  return $http.post(API + "sessions", data)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
};

Sessions.login = function(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Sessions.create(data)
    .then(function(result) {
      //do stuff
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      return resolve(result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      return reject(err);
    });
  });
};

//View
.alert.alert-danger(role="alert" ng-show="vm.error") {{vm.error}}
```

With this code the error message that's set in `newLogin` isn't displayed to the user unless I add `$scope.$digest();` after it. Am I doing something wrong here? I can log and see the error message in `catch` inside both `login` and `newLogin`. Why is digest only needed in the second version?

Comment: Show some of your `Sessions` code. If anything outside of angular core changes scope then you need to notify angular to do digest. Also use `$q` for promises since it will manage digests for you whereas `new Promise` is outside angular context

Comment: This is my Sessions code outside of `var Sessions = {}:` and `return Sessions;`. Oh, there's `var Promise = require("bluebird");` as well.

Comment: Whenever you need [watchers to be called](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) (because you have modified state), call `digest`.

Comment: Using the browser `Promise` API is problematic. You should use the `$q` service to create promises. It is better integrated with the AngularJS Framework. See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: @georgeawg Ah, I'll switch to $q then. I was using Bluebird simply because that's what someone used for a previous project I was on.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That makes sense. However it seems like both of my examples would need `digest` then right? Not just one.

Comment: Usually, you don't call `$digest()` directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call `$apply()` (typically from within a directive), which will force a `$digest()`. But in your case, the AngularJS `$q` service will take care of calling `$apply()`. For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).

Comment: @georgeawg I just switched `return new Promise(` to `return $q(` and it works exactly as expected...without `apply`! Thank you very much everyone. If someone wants to post an answer I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the browser Promise API is problematic. You should use the `$q` service to create promises. It is better integrated with the AngularJS framework. See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

Usually, you don't call `$digest()` directly in controllers or in directives. Instead, you should call `$apply()` (typically from within a directive), which will force a `$digest()`. But in your case, the AngularJS `$q` service will take care of calling `$apply()`. For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest)